# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'. This is not supported on the shared server.How to solve this?

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, shared

This is not supported on the shared hosting server, Any idea?

```
Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Can't connect to local MySQL server
through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Comment: Too often we have code with no error messages. Now we have an error message with no code.

Comment: You should contact your hosting company for the MySQL connection details. They likely host it on a different server, not localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked further and i am   using Mysql.Socket - this is not supported on the shared server. The connection should be Mysqli. When i have changed the mysql into mysqli now it is perfectly connecting.